# Converter valor monetário (string) para float Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou lendo um arquivo csv aonde uma das colunas possem valores monetários tipo '10.000,00', o pandas está interpretando como string.

Gostaria de saber se terei que converter isso na raça (iterando em todos os itens da coluna) ou se existe alguma forma mais fácil de se fazer isso?

Gostaria do valor como float, ex: 10000.00

Comment: E porque você converteria um valor monetário para `float`?

Comment: Eu quero fazer operações matemáticas sobre os valores, como string não é possível.

Comment: Com `float` não tem exatidão e dará erros de arredondamento, então não faz sentido.

Comment: Entendi o ponto...
Mas fiquei curioso, hehe, dei uma pesquisada aqui, encontrei como alternativa o 'numpy.float128' para aumentar a precisão de valores decimais, acha que é mais apropriado? O que você utilizaria?

Comment: Eu disse que não tem exatidão, não é questão de precisão, não tem como usar qualquer tipo de dado com ponto flutuante binário. Na verdade quanto maior é pior. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html

Comment: Show!! Muito Obrigado! 
Você tem razão, irei fazer às alterações para aplicar este modulo decimal. Isso deve corrigir um pequeno bug em outra aplicação minha!!

Comment: Pequeno porque você não multiplicou por 1 milhão :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uma forma que eu acho simples é usar o apply

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':pd.date_range('2015-01-02 15:00:07', periods=3),
               'col2':pd.date_range('2015-05-02 15:00:07', periods=3),
               'col3':pd.date_range('2015-04-02 15:00:07', periods=3),
               'col4':pd.date_range('2015-09-02 15:00:07', periods=3),
               'col5':[5,3,6],
               'col6':['10.000,00','10.000,00','10.000,00']})


df['col6'] = df['col6'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(".","").replace(",",".")))
print(df)
```

output

```
            col1                col2                col3  \
0 2015-01-02 15:00:07 2015-05-02 15:00:07 2015-04-02 15:00:07
1 2015-01-03 15:00:07 2015-05-03 15:00:07 2015-04-03 15:00:07
2 2015-01-04 15:00:07 2015-05-04 15:00:07 2015-04-04 15:00:07

             col4  col5     col6
0 2015-09-02 15:00:07     5  10000.0
1 2015-09-03 15:00:07     3  10000.0
2 2015-09-04 15:00:07     6  10000.0
```

Comment: Valeu Willian, vou tentar fazer isso, estava com medo do for pois o arquivo tem 150K linhas e mais para frente quero fazer me arquivos bem maiores. Mas é uma boa solução vou testar amanhã e verificar a performance.

Obrigado!!